# Build difficult computed fields in cakephp 3

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a Table, where users are listed. There we have the fields id, rating, active. So an Example could be:

```
id | rating | active | group (computed)
1  | 12     | 1      | 
2  | 1      | 0      |
3  | 25     | 1      |
4  | 20     | 1      |
5  | 21     | 0      |
6  | 12     | 1      |
...
```

My goal is to extend the fields with an other computed group field.
I expect 3 Groups of users.

- The ones that have a "0" in active field get a "-" in group field

That was the easy one and the Users with "1" in active field will get two goups assigned.

- The "better" half of the users with a better rating will get a 1 in group field
- The "worse" half of the users with a worse rating will get a 2 in group field

So the final computed table should look like

```
id | rating | active | group (computed)
1  | 12     | 1      | 1
2  | 1      | 0      | -
3  | 25     | 1      | 2
4  | 20     | 1      | 2
5  | 21     | 0      | -
6  | 12     | 1      | 1
...
```

So I have a working code, but I think this must be coded better, but I have no clue how.

Code in Controller:

```
$this->paginate = [
        'contain' => ['ExampleTableA', 'ExampleTableB']
];
$query = $this->Users->find('all')->order(['Users.first_name'=>'ASC', 'Users.last_name'=>'ASC']);

// Extending Group      
$query->formatResults(function (\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface $results) {  
    return $results->map(function ($row) {
        if($row['active'] != 1){
            $row['group'] = '-';
        }
        else{                   
            $query_active = $this->UserParticipants->find('list', array('fields' => array('Users.id')))
            ->where(['Users.active' => 1])
            ->order(['Users.rating' => 'ASC','Users.id' => 'ASC']);                  

            $array = $query_active->toList();
            $length = $query_active->count();

            $firsthalf = array_slice($array, 0, $length / 2);
            $secondhalf = array_slice($array, $length / 2);                 

            if(in_array($row['id'], $firsthalf)){
                $row['group'] = 1;
            }
            if(in_array($row['id'], $secondhalf)){
                $row['group'] = 2;
            }                   
        }
        return $row;
    });
});

$userParticipants = $this->paginate($query);
```

The Problem with my Code is, that the `$query_active` finder will be executed as many as Users exist. I can't put any options in map function.
This example Code comes from here: [Adding Calculated Fields](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-calculated-fields)

So have you any improvments or hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no clue of cakephp. But I think you should be able to move the calculation of `$firsthalf` and `$secondhalf` out of the anonymous function.

```php
$this->paginate = [
        'contain' => ['ExampleTableA', 'ExampleTableB']
];
$query = $this->Users->find('all')->order(['Users.first_name'=>'ASC', 'Users.last_name'=>'ASC']);

$query_active = $this->UserParticipants->find('list', array('fields' => array('Users.id')))
    ->where(['Users.active' => 1])
    ->order(['Users.rating' => 'ASC','Users.id' => 'ASC']);

$array = $query_active->toList();
$length = $query_active->count();
$firsthalf = array_slice($array, 0, $length / 2);
$secondhalf = array_slice($array, $length / 2); 

// Extending Group      
$query->formatResults(function (\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface $results) use ($firsthalf, $secondhalf) {  
    return $results->map(function ($row) use ($firsthalf, $secondhalf) {
        if($row['active'] != 1){
            $row['group'] = '-';
        }
        else{                   
            if(in_array($row['id'], $firsthalf)){
                $row['group'] = 1;
            }
            if(in_array($row['id'], $secondhalf)){
                $row['group'] = 2;
            }                   
        }
        return $row;
    });
});

$userParticipants = $this->paginate($query);
```

Comment: That's also what my first try was, but then I get an undefined variable at this line when I debug the variable

Comment: @Yddap17 Which variable? Which line? Did you pass through the variables with `use ($firsthalf, $secondhalf)`?

Comment: I didnt't try it with `use`, but when I try the `$firsthalf` and `$secondhalf` variables in the `else` part are null

Comment: Your Example Worked! Forgot to add the `use` in the first anonymous funciton. Thanks alot!